# android facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

I have a android application through which i have to login to facebook.
I am using the session object of facebook sdk to login.
However the login does not work if the device has the actual facebook application installed in it.

Below is my code

```
public class FacebookSettings extends FragmentActivity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static final int LOGIN = 0;
private static final int LOGGED_IN = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = LOGGED_IN +1;
private Button publishButton;
private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
private Session mSession;

private boolean isResumed = false;


@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed=false;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed=true;
}


protected static final String LOG_TAG = "FACEBOOK_TEST";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.fb_settings);
    publishButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.publishButton);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[LOGIN] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.Login_Fragment);
    fragments[LOGGED_IN] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.Logged_in_Fragment);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callBack);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (isResumed) {
        Log.d("facebook","isResumed \n\n\n\n"+state.name());

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.d("facebook","State isOpened in on session state changed");
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            publishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            showFragment(LOGGED_IN, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.d("facebook","State isClosed in on session state changed");
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            publishButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            showFragment(LOGIN, false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        Log.d("facebook","State isOpened in resume fragments\n\n\n");
        publishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showFragment(LOGGED_IN, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the user to login.
        Log.d("facebook","State isClosed in resume fragments\n\n\n");
        publishButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        showFragment(LOGIN, false);
    }
}

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


private Session.StatusCallback callBack=new StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("facebook","in status call back \n\n\n\n");
        Log.d("facebook","state\n\n\n\n"+session.isClosed());
        Log.d("facebook","state\n\n\n\n"+session.isOpened());
        Log.d("facebook","state\n\n\n\n"+state.isClosed());
        Log.d("facebook","state\n\n\n\n"+state.isOpened());
        onSessionStateChange(session,state,exception);
    }
};


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


}
```

pls help
thanks

Comment: are u integrating facebook 3.0 ?

Comment: yeah.. facebook-sdk 3.0

Comment: You can get complete login tutorial from here : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/login-with-facebook-android_108

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this :

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/applicationId" />
```

This metadata is used by the facebook sdk to attach session to your application.
You can also set it while creating a session using the builder

```
       new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(Constants.Facebook.APP_ID)
```

Refer to the AndroidManifest.xml in HelloFacebookSample

Comment: yeah this is present in my manifest , login wont be possible if tis is not present..I am able to login through the application, my application has a problem only when the actual facebook application is installed on the phone

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that key hash, which you have entered on Facebook page is different from key hash, which is sent by Facebook application. One of the solutions is to add following code in onCreate() method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
...
```

Replace com.facebook.samples.loginhowto with your package information. Look in a log for the KeyHash and add it in your developer page. 
Additional information you can find on Facebook Developer page [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/).
But remember, this is temporary solution and will most likely work only for account, from which you got key hash with Facebook application.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the same kind of issue, but it was in IPhone app. When we develop a facbook application in IPhone, login does not work , if have intalled fb application itself. 
We resolver it, put Iphone app bundle identifier in which I was created facebook app  in facebook developer page.

I hope that this kind of similar feild missing when you was created a fb app for android in db developer page. Please check it.

Comment: thank you.. can you pls tell me where in the developer page to add the app_id